# Mathematical Description of Time Speeding Up?

Tags: calculus, differentiation, mathematical-physics

People are able to experience time speeding up or slowing down. This is confusing to me on a mathematical level because dT/dT is 1. Is there some way that makes sense for this not to be 1? The speed of time seems to be a real phenomenon and in physics there is the idea of the universe either ending or not ending, which depends on the speed of time.

Comment: Could you clarify how people experience time speeding up or down? (In what sense does this happen?)

Comment: @PatrickStevens Depending on how much stuff happens per unit of time. Also on LSD time slows down I hear.

Comment: It's something to do with the brain, not with reality. One's mental model of reality can move at different rates, which may differ from the true passage of time.

Comment: What do you mean with the "speed of time" ? Do you refer to the relativity theory ?

Comment: There's a difference between the objective time $t$ and experienced time $\tau$. Thus $\frac{d\tau}{dt}$ doesn't have to be $1$.